# If C can return only one value(int , char etc.) then how does it returns character string literal(array of chars)?

Tags: c, string, char

```
char *returnString()
{
    return "hello World";
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n %p ", &returnString());
    return 0;
}
```

what does `returnString()` returns here ? does it returns address of `'h'`?
if it then where is `"hello world"` is stored(stack / heap) ? how to see (print) address of it ?

```
char Hello[] = "It's Hello";

char something[] = "something like ";

char *readInput(char str[]) {
    char *tempStr = NULL;
    if (strcmp(str, "hello") == 0)
        return Hello;

    tempStr = (char *)malloc((strlen(something)) + (strlen(str)) + 1);

    strcpy(tempStr, something);
    strcat(tempStr, str);

    return tempStr;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char *userInput[] = { "hello", "xyz", "hello",  "abc" };
    char **result = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (4));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        result[i] = (char *)malloc(15);

        result[i] = readInput(userInput[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    strcpy(Hello, "String is Changed"); // this should not affect result[0] && result[2]

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("\t\t %s", result[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What modification should be done in 2nd program so that even after this ---> `strcpy(Hello, "String is Changed");`  values of `result[0]`  and `result[2]` not get changed.

Comment: The return type is `char *`, which is a pointer to the string literal.

Comment: String literals are arrays of `char`, and when using it you get a pointer to the first element in the array, i.e. a pointer to the first character. Also note that arrays decays to a pointer to the first element, so when you do `return Hello` in the second program it's the same as doing `return &Hello[0]`

Comment: Note that in your second program you have a memory leak. You allocate memory in the loop in the `main` function, and assign it to `result[i]`. Directly afterwards you reassign to the very same `result[i]` making you lose the first pointer.

Comment: @ryan: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 3):

The statement `return "hello World";` returns a `char *`: a pointer to the first character of the string literal `"hello World"`. This string literal is stored as a null terminated array of 12 `char`. It is usually stored in memory along with other const data of the program.

Attempting to modify this array invokes undefined behavior. It should be considered `const` and handled via `const char *`. It would be safer to define this function as

```
const char *returnString(void) {
    return "hello World";
}
```

Furthermore, you should not use the `&` on the function call in your `printf` statement.  It should read:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("\n%p\n", (void*)returnString());
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your second question, you should return a copy of the string in `Hello`.  Use this simple method:

```
if (strcmp(str, "hello") == 0)
    return strdup(Hello);
```

`strdup()` is not defined in the C Standard, but is specified in the Posix standard.  If it is not available in your system, it can be defined as:

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
    char *p = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (p) strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately strdup is not in the C lib.

Comment: Detail: The string literal is stored as a null terminated <strike>`const`</strike> array of `char`.  Attempting to change the string literal is UB, but it is type `char *` and should be treated as `const char*`.

Comment: @2501: you are correct, `strdup()` is not defined in the C Standard, but it is present in many C libraries because it is part of Posix.  Why the Standard's committee would focus on some obscure extensions and fail to standardize Posix functions is incomprehensible.

Comment: I can't upvote if you don't mention the nature of this non-standard function in the answer.

Comment: @chux The type of a string literal "hello" is `char[6]` not `char*`.

Comment: @2501: I edited the answer with an explanation about `strdup()`, what do you think is missing?

Comment: @2501 True,  `"hello"` is `char[6]` and not `char *` nor `const char *`.

Answer (score 3):

The location of where a string is allocated depends how you write it. These all return strings, but in different ways:

```
const char *a()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

char *b()
{
    return strdup("hello, world");
}

char *c()
{
    char buf[16];
    strcpy(buf, "hello, world");
    return buf; /* wrong */
}

char *d()
{
    static char buf[16];
    strcpy(buf, "hello, world");
    return buf;
}

void e(char *buf)
{
    strcpy(buf, "hello, world");
}
```

`a` returns a string literal. It is stored in read-only memory and cannot be changed.

`b` returns a string allocated on the heap. It must be freed with a call to `free`.

`c` returns a string allocated on the stack. It is wrong, however, because you cannot return a pointer to a local variable, in this case `buf`. When the closing brace is reached, the object being referenced no longer exists.

`d` offers an improvement to `c`. When the variable is declared `static`, it is (on many compilers) stored in the `.bss` segment. It is not a correction, however, because it isn't thread safe.

`e` returns a string not via the return mechanism, but by filling in an address. This code is not recommended, because buffer overflows may occur. The argument to `e` can be allocated either on the stack or heap, by the caller. As long as there is enough space to perform a copy, it will work.

Improved version of `e`:

```
/* n is the size of buf, in chars */
void eImproved(char *buf, size_t n)
{
    if (n > sizeof "hello, world") /* enough room in buf for copy */
        strcpy(buf, "hello, world");
    else
        buf[0] = '\0';             /* if not enough room, make buf empty */
}
```

If you want to print the address, use `%p` in printf:

```
printf("%p", a());
```

Comment: You could use `static char buf[16] = "hello, world";` in `d` (instead of needing `strcpy()`).  You should also show `void f(char *buffer, size_t buflen) { if (buflen >= sizeof("hello world")) strcpy(buffer, "hello world"); else { assert(buflen > 0); buffer[0] = '\0'; } }`.  That avoids the risk of buffer overflow that you assert makes `e` undesirable.  How big the risk is depends on what the function does.  With the trivial ones here, the risk is low.  It is not always low.  `f` is pretty safe — the only isses relate to null pointer for the buffer or a zero size for the buffer length.

Comment: More precise: `a()` returns a pointer: `char *`.  That pointer has a value of the address of the beginning of a string literal.